# AWS Serverless: minify/uglify the sam build lambda output

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless, minify, uglifyjs

I have a few AWS Lambda functions with APIGateway. I'm using the serverless approach, packing and deploying the app using SAM CLI. It outputs the separate function built inside the `.aws-sam` directory in the project root. I'd like to minify & uglify that source code before the package actually uploads the S3 bucket for deployment. I'm referring to the [SAM CLI Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-build.html), but nothing related to customized packaging or using bundlers has been mentioned. Is there a workaround to bundle the sourcecode with minification/uglification?

Comment: is there any luck for it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom build runtime described here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/building-custom-runtimes.html

or (if you only want to use minification) you can use esbuild

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-build-typescript.html

Comment: I see `esbuild` as a possible way out here. However, I seem not to have support to uglify. is that true or I miss something?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Esbuild only has a minification feature